# Add support for AS2 adapters

Tags: spring-integration

May I know is there any plan for Spring integration to support AS2?
I found this thread however seems there is no conclusion about AS2, thanks
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SESIA-17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have enough resources in the team to deal with all the possible integrations in the world. We just concentrate on most demanded. The project is Open Source, so feel free to take our code for inspiration  to implement your own channel adapters. In the end you really can come back to us with a contribution. However the solution must comply with Open Source Licensing we support.